# Best way to achieve update state of authenticated user as reaction to changed state in system. (ASP.NET MVC website)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to achieve auto-updated notification system for web user.

Notification messages are stored in database. In way to reduce roudtrips to database the state of new notifications (count) is checked only in login process. So after user is logged in I check the new notifications count for user and I store it in cookies. So the count of new notification is static until next login.

So the question is, how to update state (count) of notifications after something is happened in the system. (New notification is saved into database for user). I think checking the DB in every http request is not the best way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is that not a good way? How many other database queries are you running per request?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Because there is most of the time there will be no new notifications so in 99% of cases the trip to db will be useless. I looking for smarter way where the system tells hey there is some new notification for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a truly optimized way to achieve that you may take a look at HTML5 WebSockets and [`SignalR`](http://signalr.net/). This will allow the server to push notifications to client browsers.

A less optimized alternative of course is to send AJAX request at regular intervals to check for updates.

Answer (score 2):

Its ok to check for new notifications on every http request.. That table will most likely sit on RAM anyway. You can also make the check on every n'th request.